# How to let two TextViews aligned to each other be "wrap_content" but within the constraints of ConstraintLayout without overflowing into each other?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout, android-design-library

I have two textViews aligned next to each other as such:
[Here is the image, I am not allowed to embed it for now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zj6RN.png)

My current layout works fine if I try to increase the text for the first text view, it remains within the constraint as it should. [Here is it how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0A33.png) and this is fine.

But when I try to do the exact opposite of this, i.e increase the width for the second textView, I expect the first one to remain in place, but the same does not happens and it overflows.[It goes out of bounds like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AagSl.png)

So I cannot understand what is it that I am doing wrong? I want both the textViews to take whatever space is available to them within the constraints. Could someone guide me where I am going wrong?
Both the textViews are chained to each other.

**Here is my current XML Code.**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryBackground">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guidelineStart"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.04" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guidelineEnd"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.96" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guidelineTop"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.04" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvStart"
        style="@style/StyleRegular"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="Text A"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/tvEnd"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/guidelineStart"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/guidelineTop" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvEnd"
        style="@style/StyleRegular"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="Text B Text B Text B Text B Text B T"
        app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/guidelineEnd"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/tvStart"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/guidelineTop" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Limit `TextView` width with `0dp`. `wrap_content` has no bounds

Comment: @StanislavBondar Which TextView do I set to 0dp? I have tried setting them both 0dp then the design does not end up being next to each other since they occupy all the available space, also I understand ```wrap_content``` and has no bounds, but is that not why we have  ```app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"```?

Comment: Could you please tell what should happen if both texts are long?

Comment: @gevondov If you could refer to the screenshot where the text of ```tvStart``` is long, how even after being long it does not overlap the other textView chained to the end. I want the same behavior to happen if I were to increase the text of ```tvEnd``` such that ```tvStart``` remains in its place and whatever other space is can be occupied. 

I just want them to be next to each other and remain within the start and end constraint and use whatever space is available between those start and end constraint.

Comment: I think you describe two different problems which have two different solutions. In first case you assume that tvStart text is fixed and tvEnd is changing. The second one is opposite case. What I want to say that your problem doesn't describe the third way when both texts are long. I just think you can't resolve your problem without realizing what should happen in third case. Don't know if I could to convey the idea

Comment: @gevondov I got it to some extent. In case both of them are long I guess they take 50% each of the space available? The thing is they both can have long or short text or both long or both short, my only concern is that they should remain within their constraints.

Comment: hello, @che10 I'm also having this problem. The same behavior I want to achieve as you've mentioned above. Did you manage to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvStart"
    style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:maxLines="1"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/tvEnd"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    tools:text="Text A Text A Text" />

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvEnd"
    style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:maxLines="1"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/tvStart"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    tools:text="Text B Text B Text B Text B Text B T" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is what the layout will look like. You can change up the `layout_width` from `0dp` to `wrap_content` and see how that works between the 2 views to get it where you want.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Experimenting with `android:maxLength=""` or `android:maxWidth=""` on first text view dynamically can give you desired result. At runtime, find the best-suited `maxLength` and `maxWidth` values based on the strings for two text views. Also, You can also check [FlexLayout](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout) or [FlowLayout](https://github.com/nex3z/FlowLayout) if they solve your UI requirement.

Answer (score 0):

This one works as you expected for shorter strings with the use of [FlexboxLayout](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout)

```
<com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:alignItems="flex_start">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:lines="1"
        tools:text="Text A" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:lines="1"
        tools:text="Text B Text B Text B Text B Text B T" />
</com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout>
```